# How to turn a Html nested list into a Python's one

Tags: python, html, html-lists

I have this kind of Html list:

```
lista = """
<ul>
<li>Arts &amp; Entertainment
    <ul>
      <li>Celebrities &amp; Entertainment News</li>
      <li>Comics &amp; Animation
        <ul>
        <li>Anime &amp; Manga</li>
        <li>Cartoons</li>
        <li>Comics</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>

"""
```

and I would like to convert it into a useful python structure for further processing:

what structure do you suggest? and also how would you do that?

Comment: Which html parser are you using?

Comment: As @jcollado suggested I'm using Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), I'd do something like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

def parseList(tag):
    if tag.name == 'ul':
        return [parseList(item)
                for item in tag.findAll('li', recursive=False)]
    elif tag.name == 'li':
        if tag.ul is None:
            return tag.text
        else:
            return (tag.contents[0].string.strip(), parseList(tag.ul))

soup = BeautifulSoup(lista)
pprint(parseList(soup.ul))
```

Example output:

```
[(u'Arts &amp; Entertainment',
  [u'Celebrities &amp; Entertainment News',
   (u'Comics &amp; Animation',
    [u'Anime &amp; Manga', u'Cartoons', u'Comics'])])]
```

Note that for list items that contain an unnumbered list, a tuple is returned in which the first element is the string in the list item and the second element is a list with the contents of the unnumbered list.

Comment: I have to confess I'm having some troubles processing it. I'd like to print the whole list maintaining the hierarchy. For example printing it with different indents...

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the Mapping Type: Dictionaries**